# Referring to the target name from the list of the prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a Makefile, I would like to refer to the target name from the list of prerequisites and to build something with it. Something of the form:

```
%.foo: $(addsuffix .bar, $(DATA_%))
  @echo $<
```

So that, supposing you have:

```
DATA_test = 1 2 3
```

When you call it as:

```
make test
```

That will expand to:

```
1.bar 2.bar 3.bar
```

Is this somehow possible? What would be a better approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Make has [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), this will probably work (I can't test it because today all I have handy is an old version).

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.foo: $$(addsuffix .bar, $$(DATA_$$*))
    @echo $^
```

Without that, I don't see any better way to do it than this:

```
define FOO_RULE
$(1).foo: $(addsuffix .bar,$(DATA_$(1)))
endef

FOO_TYPES = test real whatever

$(foreach t,$(FOO_TYPES),$(eval $(call FOO_RULE,$(t))))

%.foo:
    @echo building $@ from $^
```

Comment: Second expansion works perfectly! Thanks! I've actually tried that before, but I was not doubling the $ in front of the addsuffix. This works much better and makes perfectly sense.

Comment: The way to do it in the old days before secondary expansion and eval was available, was to take advantage of make's automatically re-made makefiles capability.  You'd write a rule to generate a makefile snippet containing the generated targets, then include that snippet.  It works well, although somewhat less efficiently and it can be tricky to debug (although eval has the same problem: at least with automatically generated makefiles you have the makefile output to look at when something goes sideways).